# Google Maps Api Javascript - How to position a marker by text location (not lat/long)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I'm using Google Maps V3 Javascript Api. Now, I'm adding markers to it. Is there any option to add the marker location without using latitude and longitude? Eg: I want to write only position: 'NewYork, USA'.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to geocode it first. You send the address to [their API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) and get the latitude and longitude back.

Comment: Thank you, but i have over 2,500 requests per day.

Comment: Hmm, there are other geocoding APIs with varying usage limits that you can try, but ultimately you will likely have to pay at that volume. Can you cache results or are they different for each user?

Comment: According to http://blog.programmableweb.com/2012/06/21/7-free-geocoding-apis-google-bing-yahoo-and-mapquest/ Yahoo allows 50,000 requests per day

Comment: The results are not different for each user, but i don't know how to cache it.

Comment: Store the results on your server. If you do the geocoding there just create a database entry for each result you get and before making a request to Google Maps check if the result is already there. Otherwise you could fetch everything on the client and transfer that data to your server. (You don't really want to accept client-provided data to server to other users, so if possible you could only cache results you personaly get.)